# ExtJS 3.3.1 - How to get each element in an array in Ext.Template

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJS and trying to use this example as a base for my code:
[grid_binding](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/examples/grid/binding.html).

I have a perl *.pm file which handles my back-end functionality.

I wrote a function of my own that is called on row selection, uses my *.pm to retrieve information and overwrites the detailPanel like so:

```
var getInfo = function(id){
var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
conn.request({
    url: request_url,
    params: {
        _state: request_state,
        _action: 'get_id_info',
        id: id
    },
    callback: function(options, success, response){
        var responseHash = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        var detailPanel = Ext.getCmp('detailPanel');
        myTpl.overwrite(detailPanel.body, responseHash);
    }

});
};
```

My responseHash contains several keys and some of these keys' value is an array.

At the moment my detailPanel looks like so:

```
// define a template to use for the detail view
var myTplMarkup = [
    "values related to this key_name: {key_name}"
];
var myTpl = new Ext.Template(myTplMarkup);
```

This prints the values related to that key separated by commas in the detailed view.

Now, I would like to access each of this values separately and incorporate it into a link (and present that link in the detailed view).

How do I do that?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Ext.Template to Ext.XTemplate and used this example to access each item in the array and generate a hyperlink fo it:

[generate_hyperlink](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?119677-Is-it-possible-to-generate-components-dynamically-in-Ext.XTemplate-from-a-datastore)

I found the Ext documentation on XTemplate to be very useful.

so now my code looks like so:

```
// define a template to use for the detail view
var myTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<p>item(s) related to this id:',
        '<tpl for="key_name">',
        '<p><a href="---url_template---{.}" target="_blank">{.}</a></p>',
        '</tpl></p>'
);
```